# I am not jailing my users well in VSFTPD (CentOS7)?

Tags: centos, partition, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed **vsftpd** and it is working properly, but my problem remains in that I only want to use the **/ftp** partition, and I have added to the end of the **/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf** file this:
**local_root=/ftp/**, but when from Filezilla I test the FTP server, I can go through all the disk:
[image]

So, how could I only show the /ftp partition?